# SMTP data error.550 b the form address doesn't match a verified sender identity

Tags: django, smtp, sendgrid

I am trying to send mail in my django project. Whenever I try to send email it shows the error like the screenshot. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqkhX.png)
I generated API in sendgrid and used it in my project. And I also disable two step verification in my email and allow less secure app enable. My setting is :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "this is the API_KEY that I generated in sendgrid"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Did you verify the domain from ```sendgrid``` that you use to sent mail

Comment: Actually I don't have a domain. I registered as a single sender on sendgrid by using my gmail.

Comment: Did you verify sender with your gmail ?

Comment: yes, I already did it. But it doesn't change anything. Show the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this setting in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#default-from-email

The setting should match your settings in SendGrid